# Data attribute refresh canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I have a circle shape that I draw via data-percent. If 90 percent it will draw 90 percent of the shape.

Every second my idea is to remove 1 percent of this square, the problem is that setting the data attribute doesnt work and if I do it via the DOM the shape doesnt update itself.

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    var charta = $(".chart");

var value = charta.data("percent");
charta.data("percent", "200");

<div class="chart" data-percent="90"></div>
```

Comment: Sorry for the previous comments... Although it works.. http://jsfiddle.net/4vs4Lrw3/

Answer (score 0):

**There is no event that triggers when a data- attribute changes**

So changing your `data-percent` attribute from 90 to 200 will always go unnoticed.

You could create a custom jQuery event that you trigger when you change `data-percent` ...

```
// tell the .chart class to listen for a custom event
// called "changedDataAttribute"
$('.chart').on('changedDataAttribute', function(e){    

    // call a function to redraw the chart
    redrawMyChart(this.id,$(this).data('percent'));

});


// chain jquery commands to first change data-percent to 200
// and then trigger the custom "changedDataAttribute" event
$('.chart').data("percent",200).trigger('changedDataAttribute'); 


// redraw the chart with id==chartId
function redrawMyChart(chartId,newPercent){
    // now redraw your chart with id==chartId at newPercent
}
```

**...But unless you need the event layer for some reason, adding it is not necessary.**

Instead, you can just directly call `redrawMyChart` whenever you change `data-percent`.

```
// redraw the chart with id==chartId
function redrawMyChart(chartId,newPercent){
    // now redraw at newPercent
}
```